# Lost my Lenovo Recovery partition

Tags: windows-7, partitioning, thinkpad

I by mistake deleted my recovery partition in my Lenovo Thinkpad E420.
How can I restore that Partition?

I tried a exe found in Program Files(x86)->Lenovo->Factory
It temporarily create that drive again, But that drive doesn't have exe file to start Factory Reset.

I even tried factory reset after F11 , but it says "Can't find any backup".

Comment: "How can i have that Partition again." - You can't.  You deleted it.  You can replicate what it does by just booting to a Windows installation disk though.

Comment: @Ramhound is right, but if you go to Lenovo Support they can load fully system again, i dont know if that have a cost for you, you should evaluate that.

Answer (score 1):

Your ability to restore your partition depends on how it was deleted and what you have done since then.

**NOTE: Backup your data. Use at your own risk.**

You can try some partition recovery tools like [MiniTool](http://www.minitool-partitionrecovery.com/recoverymore.html) or [Partition Find & Mount](http://findandmount.com/).

If you cannot recover the partition, but you need to reinstall Windows, you still have other options;

- [Order recovery media from
         Lenovo](https://www.lenovorecovery.com/Extranet/RecoveryCdRequest.aspx)
- [Make your own installation media by downloading the Windows 7 iso](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows7)